# Event handler not triggering when user created using SCIM/REST APIs for UDF

Tags: event-handling, identity, identity-management, oim, identitymanager

While creating user via OIM API--> My Event handler gets Triggered

While creating user via OIM GUI--> My Event handler gets Triggered

While creating user via OIM SCIM API--> My Event handler is NOT getting Triggered...

Any clues?

Comment: How is your handler configured? Is it conditional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Using GET schemas you will get to under which Schema the attribute would belong.(In my case I had two custom attribute one is text field and other was of type lookup.While using GET schemas I only to got to know schema for the text field as it returned nothing for the lookup field.
   "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:oracle:2.0:OIG:User").
2. Take metadata export of the file User.xml .Search for the attribute name in that file and under `<scim>` tag enter the following entry in `<value>`

   `<name>scim</name>
   <value>urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:oracle:2.0:OIG:User:<attrName></value>
   <category>properties</category>`

Then import the User.xml file

3. Restart OIM server. Then test the scenario, event handler will get triggered.
4. Although for the lookup field I didn't get it any under any schema but when I used the same schema as that of text field it started working fine.